# Calculation of hour in Excel using [h]:mm formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

```
START    END    TOTAL   TOTAL                           
21:00   3:15    6:15    6:15                            
23:25   1:11    1:46    1:46                            
20:25   5:20    8:55    8:55                            
21:25   3:08    5:43    5:43                            
22:10   2:15    4:05    4:05                            
             2786:44   26:44                            
               WRONG   RIGHT
```

Help me to solve this. I do calculate the hour in Excel 2007, from the start time and end time using the formula [h]:mm but in the end result which is in the TOTAL column, I get 2786:44 instead of the correct total of 26:44.

How did that happen, and how can I convert 2786:44 to 26:44?

Comment: What formula did you use in the `TOTAL` column? `[h]:mm` is **not** a formula.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the formula used involves adding **24** when end time is smaller than start time (to account for the extra day when passing midnight), e.g. something like this:

`=B2-A2+IF(B2<A2,24)`

if the result cells in total column are formatted as `h:mm` (rather than `[h]:mm`) you will see what looks like the right results....but that formula is **incorrect** - 24 is 24 `days` not `hours` so you are adding `24` days when you should be adding `1` day

Use 1 in place of 24 and you will get the right results and the right total, i.e.

`=B2-A2+IF(B2<A2,1)`

Comment: Aaah, you did the math :) 23 days too many * 24 * 5 is 2760. The exact amount the result is off. +1 for the fact you found it without knowing the formula for sure.

Comment: Thanks Rik, I didn't really need to do the calculation, though - there are some sites on the net that I've seen before that suggest wrong formulas of this sort - it can be confusing because if you require the result as a decimal number of hours then adding 24 is OK